# How to create Play! Framework JAVA application with JetBrains IntelliJ Idea 13? I only find the Scala project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, jetbrains-ide

How to create Play! Framework 2.3 **JAVA** application with JetBrains IntelliJ Idea 13?

I only find the Play! Framework **Scala** application in IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to create a Java Play! project from directly within IDEA. You have two options:

1. Create a scala project using IDEA and manually create new Java classes. You can then modify your routes file to call on these Java classes.
2. Create the project from the command line, then open it in IDEA. This can be done like so:

   ```
   activator new [projname] play-java
   cd [projname]
   activator idea
   ```

You should then be able to import the project into IDEA but I'm not sure how well it will work. The documentation for the "activator idea" command seems to have disappeared in the more recent versions of Play! though, so I don't know how long that feature will last.

References:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE

Comment: The solution by @javierhe is much better, and doesn't involve the command line at all.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but 'activator' command will no longer be available after May: http://www.lightbend.com/activator/docs

Answer (score 4):

You can choose "Java Web Application", then on the next screen, you have a template for Play! Applications:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i did it. Create java app with activator in command line as normal.

in intellij:

IntelliJ IDEA lets you import an existing Play 2.x project.

On the main menu, select File | New | Project from Existing Sources.
In the window that opens, select a file that you want to import and click OK. The Import project wizard opens.
On the first page of the wizard, select Import project from external model option and choose SBT project from the list. Click Next.

You can run the created application and view the result in the default browser http://localhost:9000. To run a Play application:

Create a new Run Configuration – From the main menu, select Run -> Edit Configurations
Click on the + to add a new configuration
From the list of configurations, choose “SBT Task”
In the “tasks” input box, simply put “run”
Apply changes and select OK.
Now you can choose “Run” from the main Run menu and run your application.

it works. i see the "welcome to play" page in localhost:9000.

Its awesome because to edit the app you have to debug it live and see the changes occur in the browser. much more fluid then Eclipse.